# What are the vulnerability points of SSL data and encrypted cookies?

Tags: authentication, cookies, ssl, cryptography

I was trying to understand the determining factor for breaking the encryption of SSL and encrypted cookies.

In public/private key, which is used by SSL, the key bit is the determining factor for breaking the encryption.

Similarly what is the determining factor for breaking encryption of encrypted cookies.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Breaking the actual crypto is pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In public/private key, which is used by SSL, the key bit is the determining factor for breaking the encryption.

This is meaningless. SSL only uses the public and private keys for signing and verifying certificates. The actual encryption uses symmetric one-time session keys. Your question remains entirely obscure.